# Setting the from name in a javax.mail.MimeMessage?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, mime-message

Currently, our application uses a javax.mail to send email, using javax.mail.MailMessage. We set the From headers of the email this way:

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mail@companyxyz.com"));
```

This works just fine, but we'd like to make the "From" section a little more user-friendly. Currently, someone receiving an email will see "mail@companyxyz.com" in the "From" section of their inbox. Instead, we'd like them to see "Company XYZ" there. I figure this is probably done with the addHeader() method, but I'm not sure what the header name would be.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

OK, reading documentation about ALL the classes involved would have been helpful. The correct syntax should be

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("mail@companyxyz.com", "Company XYZ"));
```

Source: https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html

Comment: It might be worth testing whether "Company XYZ <mail@companyxyz.com>" allows you to use the IntenetAddress(String, boolean) constructor to strictly check the address syntax but still have a personal name.

Answer (score 23):

If you want to store the email + the name in one string (easier than keeping two string):

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("Company XYZ <mail@companyxyz.com>"));
```

Comment: +1 because this solution works also with `SimpleMimeMessage` of Spring Mail, where no instance of `MimeMessage` can be accessed and no `InternetAddress` is used directly. It operates only on strings.

Answer (score 3):

In case when I used localized text with special characters like \u00FA I had problems with encoding email address alias for some pop3 clients if I'd used just

```
MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(session);
m.setFrom();
```

It can be resolved by separate email address and alias by invoke:

```
MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(session);
            m.setFrom(new InternetAddress(session.getProperty("mail.from"), session.getProperty("mail.from.alias"),"UTF8"));
```

ref: https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#InternetAddress(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

```
ic = new InitialContext();

final Session session = (Session) ic.lookupLink(snName);
final Properties props = session.getProperties();

props.put("mail.from", mailFrom); //blabla@mail.com
props.put("mail.from.alias", mailName);//"joao Ninguem"

// Create a message with the specified information.
final MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setSentDate(new Date());

msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(session.getProperty("mail.from"), session.getProperty("mail.from.alias"), "UTF8"));


msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(mailTo, false));
msg.setContent(body, "text/html");

// Create a transport.
Transport.send(msg);
```

Comment: Please explain a bit about what you are doing as well.