# JavaMail stopped working when running on Tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, email, tomcat, jakarta-mail

Hello I am a beginner trying to get a mail notification service run on my Tomcat server. When I run this code locally it works but not when I deploy it on remote server.
I get "javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address".
I have a SSL certificate on my server, can it be the cause of this?

Please be nice, and if you think I have forgotten something, write it and Ill update the post.
Thank you, here is my code.

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="25" />
    <property name="username" value="mymail@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="mypassword" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

MailService.java

```
@Autowired
private MailSender mailSender;

public void sendEventMailToUser(Event event) {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
    message.setTo(event.getUser().getEmail().trim());
    message.setSubject("appName");
    message.setText("Mymessage");
    mailSender.send(message);

}
```

From my mail debug

```
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 25, isSSL false
220 mx.google.com ESMTP ld10sm15750527lab.8 - gsmtp
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.gmail.com", port: 25

EHLO
250-mx.google.com at your service, [91.189.44.73]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 CHUNKING
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
STARTTLS
220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
EHLO
250-mx.google.com at your service, [91.189.44.73]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250 CHUNKING
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
c2FtYnVoYXV0b21haWxAZ21haWwuY29t
334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
UGFzc1dvcmQ0Tm93
235 2.7.0 Accepted
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:906)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:416)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:306)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:296)
    at se.whiffdev.sambuh.utilities.MailService.sendEventMailToUser(MailService.java:68)
    at se.whiffdev.sambuh.service.impl.EventServiceImpl.updateEvent(EventServiceImpl.java:44)
    at se.whiffdev.sambuh.mvc.adminuser.AdminUserCalendarController.adminUserCreateUpdateCalendar(AdminUserCalendarController.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
QUIT
221 2.0.0 closing connection ld10sm15750527lab.8 - gsmtp
```

Comment: So, what is the local email address? What was it when you were running this code successfully on your dev machine? (BTW, nicely put question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you lack the From field.

Try something like.

```
message.setFrom("name@organization.com");
```

See also

[Setting the from name in a javax.mail.MimeMessage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567467/setting-the-from-name-in-a-javax-mail-mimemessage)

which describes a non-identical but similar issue.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Good luck.